# How to take screenshot and display the same in the Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, screenshot, display

I am making a program that with one button click, takes a screenshot of the open window and then display the same in the GUI but unable to do so.
I could take the screenshot and then save it, but cannot display it.
This is my code to screenshot:

```
def screenshot():
    myscreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    save_path = asksaveasfilename()
    myscreenshot.save(save_path + "_screenshot.png")


button = tk.Button(window, text="Take screenshot", command=screenshot, font=10, bg='red')
button.pack()
```

This is the code which works. Can someone help me in this?
THanks

Comment: You can use a `Label` to show the image.

Comment: [Tkinter: How to load, display and replace image on Label, Button or Canvas](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-how-to-load-display-and-replace-image-on-label-button-or-canvas-gb.html)

Comment: Thanks, @furas , I'll check the link